# Не работает transition c box-shadow

Tags: html, css, transition, box-shadow

Не работает transition при hover на кнопке. Сам box-shadow появляется,но без анимации. Что примечательно на пару блоков выше, точно такой же код работает прекрасно, а здесь не работает вообще.
JsFiddle для удобства https://jsfiddle.net/TomatoBrain/cj94b2ft/

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer--flex">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <div class="footer__news">
            <div class="footer__news--title footer--title">
              <h3>Get Newsletter</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="footer__news--input">
              <input type="text" class="footer__news--email" placeholder="EMAIL">
              <button class="footer__news--submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

```
.footer {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.footer--flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer__news--email {
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 20px;
}

.footer__news--submit {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(14, 15, 15, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(14, 15, 15, 0.25);
  border: 1px solid #ff6d6d;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ff6d6d;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer__news--submit:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ff6d6d inset, 0 0 0 4px white inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ff6d6d inset, 0 0 0 4px white inset;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно анимировать и внешние и внутренние тени элемента, то опиши их всех и в обычных стилях и для `:hover`. Т.е. соль в конкретизации начальных и конечных значений.

Прототип накидала

```css
button {
  box-shadow:
      0 0 0 10px pink,
      0 0 0 15px red,
      inset 0 0 0 0,
      inset 0 0 0 0;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow:
      0 0 0 0,
      0 0 0 0,
      inset 0 0 0 2px hsl(0, 0%, 30%),
      inset 0 0 0 5px hsl(0, 0%, 10%) ;
}
```

```html
<button>cancel</button>
```

p.s. лучше вынести свойство `transition` из `:hover` к обычным стилям, если нужно, чтобы анимация работала не только, когда элемент становится `hover`, но и когда возвращается в нормальное состояние.